# ¿Como aplicar salto de pagina en HTML, para realizar impresión?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este código, al darle click al boton, ejecuta el print, pero quisiera cada tabla salga en una hoja diferente. En si un salto de pagina para cada tabla. Estuve investigando pero no encontré algo claro para lo que quiero hacer. La idea es realizar una impresión de n tablas, pero una en cada hoja.

Quisiera ayuda en esto por favor, Gracias.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="window.print()">Print this page</button>
<h3>Tabla A</h3>
<table style="width:100%" border="2">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h3>Tabla B</h3>
<table style="width:100%" border="2">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: probá con [`table {break-after: always;}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after) en un [`@media print`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) , mas info en [MDN medios paginados](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Paged_Media)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.- Lo que puedes hacer es que a tus tablas les agregues la propiedad `break-after: page;`

```
table {
  break-after: page;
}
```

2.- Esto hara que al momento de impresion haga un salto de linea en cada tabla.

3.- Te recomiendo leer mas sobre como funciona : `break-after: page;`

[break-after:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after)

4.- Te dejo un ejemplo practico con tu propio codigo.

```css
table {
  break-after: page;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="window.print()">Print this page</button>
<h3>Tabla A</h3>
<table style="width:100%" border="2">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h3>Tabla B</h3>
<table style="width:100%" border="2">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```